# Having an issue getting a value returned from inside a nested function in React. Might be scope, but maybe async issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, google-distancematrix-api

I'm connecting a custom location api to google maps. On each locations longLat property I am calling a function `calculateDistances` to get the arguments needed for a Google Distance Matrix API call.

Here is where that call is happening:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.locations).map((i) => {
   let locale = this.state.locations[i];
   return <Location name={locale.name}
   address={locale.address}
   longLat={locale.longLat}
   needsCode={locale.needsCode}
   needsKey={locale.needsKey}
   distances={this.calculateDistances(locale.longLat)}
   handicapAccess={locale.handicapAccess}
   code={locale.code}
   id={locale.id} />
})},
```

The actual Google Distance Matrix API call is then nested within the `calculateDistances` function. Within this nested function I set the distance that is returned from the call as a variable: 'dist'.

```
calculateDistances(longLat) {
    const origins = [Object.values(this.state.currentLocation).join()];
    const destinations = [Object.values(longLat).join()];
    const travelMode = this.state.travelMode.length ? this.state.travelMode : 'WALKING';
    distance.matrix(origins, destinations, travelMode, (err, distances) => {
      let dist = distances.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
    })
    return dist;
}
```

This is working great and within the nested function dist is being defined correctly. However, I cannot get the `dist` variable to return from the whole `calculateDistances` function.

So... `distance.matrix` is making the api call (google-distance-matrix is imported as `distance` at the top of the component) and getting the `dist` variable set correctly.

How do I get dist to be returned by the overall `calculateDistances` function? As of right now it is returning `undefined`.

Comment: I think the short answer is you can't. Since `distance.matrix` is async, your `calculateDistances` function will return before the `distance.matrix` call is done. How are you trying to use `calculateDistances`? Maybe the solution lies in how you intend to use that function.